# Can zebra technologies ZTC gc420t EPL print the file which contains ZPL code?

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii, epl

ZPL Code:

Task.txt

```
^XA

^FO30,390^GFA,8064,8064,32,,:::::::::::::::::::K07VFCM03FC003FE003VFE,K0WFCM07FE007FE003WF,::::::::K0FFCR07FCR07FE003FER03FF,:::::::::K0FFCR07FCW03FER03FF,K0FFC007LFC007FC007FE007FEM03FE003LFE003FF,::::::::K0FFC007LFC007FCW03FE003LFE003FF,K0FFC007LFC007FCR07FE003FE003LFE003FF,:::::::::K0FFC007LFC007FCJ01FF801JFE003FE003LFE003FF,::::::::K0FFCR07FCJ01FF801FF8J03FER03FF,K0FFCR07FCJ01MF8J03FER03FF,::::::::K0FFCR07FCM07FEM03FER03FF,K0WFC007FE007FE007FE003WF,::::::::gK07FE007FE,::::::::::K0MFC007QFE007FE007LFEM03FE,::::::::K0MFC007QFE007FE003LFEM03FE,K0FFC007FCJ01FFK07FE007JF800FF800FF800FF800FF8,::::::::K07FC007FCJ01FFK07FC007JF800FF800FF800FF800FF8,P07FC007FC007FCJ01FF801FF800MF800MF8,:::::::::M01FFK07JF001FF001RF800MF800JFE,M01FFK07JF001FF801RF800MF800KF,M01FFK07JF001FF001RF800MF800KF,:::::::K07JF001RF001MF801MF800MF8,K0KF001RF001MF800MF800MF8,:::::::K0KF001RF801MF801MF800MF8,gK0403JFEM03FEM03JF8,gK07LFEM03FEM03JF8,::::::::gK07FE,K0WFC007FEM07FEM03FEM03FF,::::::::K0FFCR07FC007FE,K0FFCR07FC007LFEM03FEM03JF8,::::::::K0FFCR07FC007FER03FEM03FF,K0FFC007LFC007FC007FEM07FE003FE003FE003FE003FF,::::::::K0FFC007LFC007FC,K0FFC007LFC007FCJ01FF801FF801FF800FF800FF800FF8,K0FFC007LFC007FCJ01FF801FF800FF800FF800FF800FF8,:::::::K0FFC007LFC007FCO01FF800FF800FF800FF8,K0FFC007LFC007FC007FE007JF800MF800JFE003FF,::::::::K0FFCR07FC007FEJ01FF801FF801FF800FFC,K0FFCR07FC007JF801MF800MF800FF8,::::::::K0FFCR07FC007JF801FF801FF800FFC01FF800FFC,K0WFC007JF801FF800MF800PF,:::::::K0WFC007JF801FF801MF800PF,K07VFC007JFI0FF800MF800OFE,,:::::::::::::::::::^FS

^FO30,25^GFA,1512,1512,14,,:::R08,P07FFE,O07JFE,N01LF8,N07LFC,M01NF,M03NF8,M0OFC,L01PF,L03PF8,L07PF8,L0QFC,L0QFE,K01RF,K03RF8,:K07RFC,K07RFE,K0SFE,::J01SFC078,J01SFC001,J01SF80804,J03SFJ01,J03SF01I08,J03RFE02I02,J03RFEK01,J03RFC04J08,J03RF808J04,J03RF808,J03RF01,J03RFM01,J03QFE02,J07QFC04L08,I03RFC04,I07RF808L04,I0SF,003MF01F01F01,003LFE01F03E02M02,007LFE03E03EO02,00MFC07E07C04M02,01MFC07C0F8,01MF80F80F808,03MF01F81F01,03MF01F03F,07LFE03F03E02,07LFE03E07C04,07LFC07C07C,07LF80FC0F808,07LF81F81F81O02,07LF01F01F01O02,07LF03F03E02,07KFE03E03E,07KFC07E07C04O04,07KFC0FC0FC08O04,07KF80F80F8Q08,07KF81F81F01P08,03KF03F03FQ01,03JFE03E03E02,01JFE07E07C04O02,01JFC07C07CQ04,00JFC0FC0F808O08,007IF81F81F8P01,003IF01F01F01O02,001IF03F03E02,I0FFE07E03EP01,I07FE07E07C04N04,I01FC0FC0F808M01,J0F81F80F808M0C,L01F80F00MFE,,::::::::::03C0FF807F8J07F81FE01FF,03C0FFC07FEJ07F81FF01FF8,03C0FFE07FEJ07F81FF81FFC,03C0F3E079FJ07801E7C1F7C,03C0F1E078FJ07801E7C1E3C,03C0F1E078FJ07801C3C1E3C,03C0F3E079EJ07801E781E3C,03C0FFC07FCJ07F01FF81FFC,03C0FFC07FCJ07F01FF01FF8,03C0FFC07FEJ07F01FF01FF,03C0F9E079F07E07801FF01F8,03C0F1E078F07E07801CF01F,03C0F0F078F07E07801CF01E,03C0F1E079FJ07801C781E,03C0FFE07FFJ07F81E781E,03C0FFE07FEJ07F81E7C1E,03C0FF807FCJ07F81E3C1E,01807C003EK03F00C180C,,:::^FS

^CF0,30
^FO490,40^GB310,45,45^FS
^FO500,50^FR^AC^FDPACKING LIST^FS

^CF0,35
^FO30,150^FDAct #: 12345^FS
^FO29,151^FDAct #: 12345^FS

^FO30,178^FDPicker: John Dow^FS
^FO29,179^FDPicker: John Dow^FS

^FO625,150^FDOrder #: 65785^FS
^FO626,151^FDOrder #: 65785^FS

^FO575,178^FDOrder Date: 8/15/17^FS
^FO576,179^FDOrder Date: 8/15/17^FS

^FO30,220^GB755,180,1^FS
^FO400,220^GB1,180,1^FS

^CF0,30
^FO80,250^FDONE STOP TOBACCO, INC^FS
^FO79,251^FDONE STOP TOBACCO, INC^FS


^CF0,30
^FO140,280^FDSamuel Johnson^FS
^FO150,305^FD877.566.6786^FS

^CF0,36
^FO60,360^FDTruck#^FS
^FO59,361^FDTruck#^FS

^CF0,36
^FO133,360^FD:^FS

^CF0,36
^FO150,360^FD102^FS

^CF0,36
^FO240,360^FDStop#^FS
^FO239,361^FDStop#^FS

^CF0,36
^FO303,360^FD:^FS

^CF0,36
^FO323,360^FD02^FS

^CF0,30
^FO420,250^FDShip to:^FS
^FO419,251^FDShip to:^FS

^CF0,30
^FO420,280^FD51w56 South Main Street,^FS
^FO420,310^FDBlock # 14^FS
^FO420,340^FDAtlantic Beach, South Carolina,^FS
^FO420,370^FD89764 - USA^FS

^CF0,55
^FO430,500^FDBOX:^FS

^CF0,200
^FO700,450^FD9^FS

^CF0,30
^FO25,630^GB760,45,45^FS
^FO35,640^FR^FDItem #^FS
^FO145,640^FR^FDDescription^FS
^FO700,640^FR^FDQty^FS

^FO25,670^GB760,460,1^FS
^FO130,670^GB0,460,0^FS
^FO650,670^GB1,460,1^FS

^CF0,35
^FO35,690^FD678998^FS
^FO35,720^FD677868^FS
^FO35,750^FD677848^FS
^FO35,780^FD678888^FS
^FO35,810^FD679838^FS
^FO35,840^FD678588^FS

^CF0,35
^FO150,690^FDDescription 1^FS
^FO150,720^FDDescription 2^FS
^FO150,750^FDDescription 1^FS
^FO150,780^FDDescription 1^FS
^FO150,810^FDDescription 1^FS
^FO150,840^FDDescription 1^FS

^CF0,35
^FO710,690^FD1^FS
^FO710,720^FD2^FS
^FO710,750^FD1^FS
^FO710,780^FD1^FS
^FO710,810^FD1^FS
^FO710,840^FD10^FS

^CF0,30
^FO70,1150^FDHave a Question? Call today: (888) 484-6872^FS

^FO490,1145^FD.^FS
^FO489,1146^FD.^FS
^FO491,1147^FD.^FS

^CF0,30
^FO525,1150^FDwww.usawdistributing.com^FS

^CF0,30
^FO200,1183^FD203 Blount Street, Fayetteville, NC 28301 - USA^FS

^XZ
```

I have Zebra Technologies ZTC GC420t (EPL) printer connected thorough USB to my Mac.

I have 4 drivers :

1. Zebra EPL1 label Printer
2. Zebra EPL2 label Printer
3. Zebra EPL3 Label Printer
4. Zebra ZPL label Printer.

I have Selected Zebra ZPL label Printer.

I am new in ZPL.

1. What should be the extension of file which contains ZPL code?
2. What should be the proper driver of Zebra ZTC gc420t(EPL) to print ZPL code?
3. Is it possible that Zebra ZTC GC420t (EPL) can print  ZPL code? If yes, then how?

Problem: I wanted the output of my ZPL code like this [ZPL Viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EFO30%2C390%5EGFA%2C8064%2C8064%2C32%2C%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK07VFCM03FC003FE003VFE%2CK0WFCM07FE007FE003WF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FCR07FE003FER03FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FCW03FER03FF%2CK0FFC007LFC007FC007FE007FEM03FE003LFE003FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFC007LFC007FCW03FE003LFE003FF%2CK0FFC007LFC007FCR07FE003FE003LFE003FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFC007LFC007FCJ01FF801JFE003FE003LFE003FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FCJ01FF801FF8J03FER03FF%2CK0FFCR07FCJ01MF8J03FER03FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FCM07FEM03FER03FF%2CK0WFC007FE007FE007FE003WF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AgK07FE007FE%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0MFC007QFE007FE007LFEM03FE%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0MFC007QFE007FE003LFEM03FE%2CK0FFC007FCJ01FFK07FE007JF800FF800FF800FF800FF8%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK07FC007FCJ01FFK07FC007JF800FF800FF800FF800FF8%2CP07FC007FC007FCJ01FF801FF800MF800MF8%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AM01FFK07JF001FF001RF800MF800JFE%2CM01FFK07JF001FF801RF800MF800KF%2CM01FFK07JF001FF001RF800MF800KF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK07JF001RF001MF801MF800MF8%2CK0KF001RF001MF800MF800MF8%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0KF001RF801MF801MF800MF8%2CgK0403JFEM03FEM03JF8%2CgK07LFEM03FEM03JF8%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AgK07FE%2CK0WFC007FEM07FEM03FEM03FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FC007FE%2CK0FFCR07FC007LFEM03FEM03JF8%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FC007FER03FEM03FF%2CK0FFC007LFC007FC007FEM07FE003FE003FE003FE003FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFC007LFC007FC%2CK0FFC007LFC007FCJ01FF801FF801FF800FF800FF800FF8%2CK0FFC007LFC007FCJ01FF801FF800FF800FF800FF800FF8%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFC007LFC007FCO01FF800FF800FF800FF8%2CK0FFC007LFC007FC007FE007JF800MF800JFE003FF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FC007FEJ01FF801FF801FF800FFC%2CK0FFCR07FC007JF801MF800MF800FF8%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0FFCR07FC007JF801FF801FF800FFC01FF800FFC%2CK0WFC007JF801FF800MF800PF%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AK0WFC007JF801FF801MF800PF%2CK07VFC007JFI0FF800MF800OFE%2C%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%5EFS%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%5EFO30%2C25%5EGFA%2C1512%2C1512%2C14%2C%2C%3A%3A%3AR08%2CP07FFE%2CO07JFE%2CN01LF8%2CN07LFC%2CM01NF%2CM03NF8%2CM0OFC%2CL01PF%2CL03PF8%2CL07PF8%2CL0QFC%2CL0QFE%2CK01RF%2CK03RF8%2C%3AK07RFC%2CK07RFE%2CK0SFE%2C%3A%3AJ01SFC078%2CJ01SFC001%2CJ01SF80804%2CJ03SFJ01%2CJ03SF01I08%2CJ03RFE02I02%2CJ03RFEK01%2CJ03RFC04J08%2CJ03RF808J04%2CJ03RF808%2CJ03RF01%2CJ03RFM01%2CJ03QFE02%2CJ07QFC04L08%2CI03RFC04%2CI07RF808L04%2CI0SF%2C003MF01F01F01%2C003LFE01F03E02M02%2C007LFE03E03EO02%2C00MFC07E07C04M02%2C01MFC07C0F8%2C01MF80F80F808%2C03MF01F81F01%2C03MF01F03F%2C07LFE03F03E02%2C07LFE03E07C04%2C07LFC07C07C%2C07LF80FC0F808%2C07LF81F81F81O02%2C07LF01F01F01O02%2C07LF03F03E02%2C07KFE03E03E%2C07KFC07E07C04O04%2C07KFC0FC0FC08O04%2C07KF80F80F8Q08%2C07KF81F81F01P08%2C03KF03F03FQ01%2C03JFE03E03E02%2C01JFE07E07C04O02%2C01JFC07C07CQ04%2C00JFC0FC0F808O08%2C007IF81F81F8P01%2C003IF01F01F01O02%2C001IF03F03E02%2CI0FFE07E03EP01%2CI07FE07E07C04N04%2CI01FC0FC0F808M01%2CJ0F81F80F808M0C%2CL01F80F00MFE%2C%2C%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A03C0FF807F8J07F81FE01FF%2C03C0FFC07FEJ07F81FF01FF8%2C03C0FFE07FEJ07F81FF81FFC%2C03C0F3E079FJ07801E7C1F7C%2C03C0F1E078FJ07801E7C1E3C%2C03C0F1E078FJ07801C3C1E3C%2C03C0F3E079EJ07801E781E3C%2C03C0FFC07FCJ07F01FF81FFC%2C03C0FFC07FCJ07F01FF01FF8%2C03C0FFC07FEJ07F01FF01FF%2C03C0F9E079F07E07801FF01F8%2C03C0F1E078F07E07801CF01F%2C03C0F0F078F07E07801CF01E%2C03C0F1E079FJ07801C781E%2C03C0FFE07FFJ07F81E781E%2C03C0FFE07FEJ07F81E7C1E%2C03C0FF807FCJ07F81E3C1E%2C01807C003EK03F00C180C%2C%2C%3A%3A%3A%5EFS%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO490%2C40%5EGB310%2C45%2C45%5EFS%0A%5EFO500%2C50%5EFR%5EAC%5EFDPACKING%20LIST%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C35%0A%5EFO30%2C150%5EFDAct%20%23%3A%2012345%5EFS%0A%5EFO29%2C151%5EFDAct%20%23%3A%2012345%5EFS%0A%0A%5EFO30%2C178%5EFDPicker%3A%20John%20Dow%5EFS%0A%5EFO29%2C179%5EFDPicker%3A%20John%20Dow%5EFS%0A%0A%5EFO625%2C150%5EFDOrder%20%23%3A%2065785%5EFS%0A%5EFO626%2C151%5EFDOrder%20%23%3A%2065785%5EFS%0A%0A%5EFO575%2C178%5EFDOrder%20Date%3A%208%2F15%2F17%5EFS%0A%5EFO576%2C179%5EFDOrder%20Date%3A%208%2F15%2F17%5EFS%0A%0A%5EFO30%2C220%5EGB755%2C180%2C1%5EFS%0A%5EFO400%2C220%5EGB1%2C180%2C1%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO80%2C250%5EFDONE%20STOP%20TOBACCO%2C%20INC%5EFS%0A%5EFO79%2C251%5EFDONE%20STOP%20TOBACCO%2C%20INC%5EFS%0A%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO140%2C280%5EFDSamuel%20Johnson%5EFS%0A%5EFO150%2C305%5EFD877.566.6786%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C36%0A%5EFO60%2C360%5EFDTruck%23%5EFS%0A%5EFO59%2C361%5EFDTruck%23%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C36%0A%5EFO133%2C360%5EFD%3A%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C36%0A%5EFO150%2C360%5EFD102%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C36%0A%5EFO240%2C360%5EFDStop%23%5EFS%0A%5EFO239%2C361%5EFDStop%23%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C36%0A%5EFO303%2C360%5EFD%3A%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C36%0A%5EFO323%2C360%5EFD02%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO420%2C250%5EFDShip%20to%3A%5EFS%0A%5EFO419%2C251%5EFDShip%20to%3A%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO420%2C280%5EFD51w56%20South%20Main%20Street%2C%5EFS%0A%5EFO420%2C310%5EFDBlock%20%23%2014%5EFS%0A%5EFO420%2C340%5EFDAtlantic%20Beach%2C%20South%20Carolina%2C%5EFS%0A%5EFO420%2C370%5EFD89764%20-%20USA%5EFS%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C55%0A%5EFO430%2C500%5EFDBOX%3A%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C200%0A%5EFO700%2C450%5EFD9%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO25%2C630%5EGB760%2C45%2C45%5EFS%0A%5EFO35%2C640%5EFR%5EFDItem%20%23%5EFS%0A%5EFO145%2C640%5EFR%5EFDDescription%5EFS%0A%5EFO700%2C640%5EFR%5EFDQty%5EFS%0A%0A%5EFO25%2C670%5EGB760%2C460%2C1%5EFS%0A%5EFO130%2C670%5EGB0%2C460%2C0%5EFS%0A%5EFO650%2C670%5EGB1%2C460%2C1%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C35%0A%5EFO35%2C690%5EFD678998%5EFS%0A%5EFO35%2C720%5EFD677868%5EFS%0A%5EFO35%2C750%5EFD677848%5EFS%0A%5EFO35%2C780%5EFD678888%5EFS%0A%5EFO35%2C810%5EFD679838%5EFS%0A%5EFO35%2C840%5EFD678588%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C35%0A%5EFO150%2C690%5EFDDescription%201%5EFS%0A%5EFO150%2C720%5EFDDescription%202%5EFS%0A%5EFO150%2C750%5EFDDescription%201%5EFS%0A%5EFO150%2C780%5EFDDescription%201%5EFS%0A%5EFO150%2C810%5EFDDescription%201%5EFS%0A%5EFO150%2C840%5EFDDescription%201%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C35%0A%5EFO710%2C690%5EFD1%5EFS%0A%5EFO710%2C720%5EFD2%5EFS%0A%5EFO710%2C750%5EFD1%5EFS%0A%5EFO710%2C780%5EFD1%5EFS%0A%5EFO710%2C810%5EFD1%5EFS%0A%5EFO710%2C840%5EFD10%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO70%2C1150%5EFDHave%20a%20Question%3F%20Call%20today%3A%20(888)%20484-6872%5EFS%0A%0A%5EFO490%2C1145%5EFD.%5EFS%0A%5EFO489%2C1146%5EFD.%5EFS%0A%5EFO491%2C1147%5EFD.%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO525%2C1150%5EFDwww.usawdistributing.com%5EFS%0A%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO200%2C1183%5EFD203%20Blount%20Street%2C%20Fayetteville%2C%20NC%2028301%20-%20USA%5EFS%0A%0A%0A%0A%5EXZ%0A), but I am only getting text, not the output.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. I believe a .zpl file extension is correct, but I think it should also work with a .txt extension.
2. Also, you should be able to print ZPL to a ZTC GC420t, because it's product page says that ZPL II is supported on this printer.
3. Lastly, to send a ZPL file to a printer via USB on a Mac, you have to use the CUPs driver. You can find tutorials on setting it up for a Zebra printer here:

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/mac-linux-or-unix-driver-suggestions-for-zebra-printers.html

Comment: in mac os 10.12 i have CUPS driver install version 2.2.0 , so what settings i need to do to in order to acheive my task.?

Answer (score 0):

If you just "Print" the ZPL on the mac, you'll just get a render of the text you're sending regardless of the driver. (but you should use EPL2 or ZPL for best output of a standard "Print") You should be OK to use the OS driver, no need for the CUPS stuff. You just send to the device using command line...

```
lpr -P <PRINTER_NAME> -o raw <FILENAME.zpl>
```